# Failed Assertion Using HOGDescriptor

Tags: opencv, histogram

Ok, so I've decided that using a histogram of oriented gradients is a better method for image fingerprinting vs. creating a histogram of sobel derivatives. I think I finally have it mostly figured out but when I test my code I get the following:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((winSize.width - blockSize.width) % blockStride.width == 0 && (winSize.height - blockSize.height) % blockStride.height == 0).

As of now I'm just trying to figure out how to compute the HOG correctly and see the results; but not visually, I just want some very basic output to see if the HOG was created. Then I'll figure out how to use it in image comparison.

**Here is my sample code:**

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
//    Initialize string variables.
string thePath, img, hogSaveFile;
thePath = "/Users/Mikie/Documents/Xcode/images/";
img = thePath + "HDimage.jpg";
hogSaveFile = thePath + "HDimage.yml";
//    Create mats.
Mat src;
//    Load image as grayscale.
src = imread(img, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
//    Verify source loaded.
if(src.empty()){
    cout << "No image data. \n ";
    return -1;
}else{
    cout << "Image loaded. \n" << "Size: " << src.cols << " X " << src.rows << "." << "\n";

}

//    Initialize float variables.
float imgWidth, imgHeight, newWidth, newHeight;
imgWidth = src.cols;
imgHeight = src.rows;
newWidth = 320;
newHeight = (imgHeight/imgWidth)*newWidth;
Mat dst = Mat::zeros(newHeight, newWidth, CV_8UC3);
resize(src, dst, Size(newWidth, newHeight), CV_INTER_LINEAR);
//    Was resize successful?
if (dst.rows < src.rows && dst.cols < src.cols) {
    cout << "Resize successful. \n" << "New size: " << dst.cols << " X " << dst.rows << "." << "\n";
} else {
    cout << "Resize failed. \n";
    return -1;
}

vector<float>theHOG(Mat dst);{
    if (dst.empty()) {
        cout << "Image lost. \n";
    } else {
        cout << "Setting up HOG. \n";
    }
    imshow("Image", dst);
    bool gammaC = true;
    int nlevels = HOGDescriptor::DEFAULT_NLEVELS;
    Size winS(newWidth, newHeight);
//        int block_size = 16;
//        int block_stride= 8;
//        int cell_size = 8;
    int gbins = 9;
    vector<float> descriptorsValues;
    vector<Point> locations;
    HOGDescriptor hog(Size(320, 412), Size(16, 16), Size(8, 8), Size(8, 8), gbins, -1, HOGDescriptor::L2Hys, 0.2, gammaC, nlevels);
    hog.compute(dst, descriptorsValues, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), locations);
    printf("descriptorsValues.size() = %ld \n", descriptorsValues.size()); //prints 960
    for (int i = 0; i <descriptorsValues.size(); i++) {
        cout << descriptorsValues[i] << endl;
    }
}
cvWaitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I messed around with different variables to define the sizes but to no avail so, I commented them out and tried manually setting them. Still nothing. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: What line does the assertion occur on?

Comment: It says it occurs on line 65 of hog.cpp but I find no mention of which line within the actual code above but I think it's line 68 where I define the HOGDescriptor.

Comment: Finding the line the assertion occurs on should be the first thing you try. Can you see the call stack when the assertion occurs?

Comment: Ok, I'm using xCode and it looks it isn't call stack friendly but I think I have it setup correctly now. It seems like the error occurs on line 77 or 78. Here's 77: `HOGDescriptor hog(Size(320, 412), Size(16, 16), Size(8, 8), Size(8, 8), gbins, -1, HOGDescriptor::L2Hys, 0.2, gammaC, nlevels);`
and 78:
        `hog.compute(dst, descriptorsValues, Size(0,0), Size(0,0), locations);`.

Comment: That's what I found, too. :) Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are initializing the `HOGDescriptor` incorrectly.
The assertion states that each of the first three input parameters must satisfy the constraint:

```
(winSize - blockSize) % blockStride == 0
```

in both `height` and `width` dimensions.

The problem is that `winSize.height` does not satisfy this constraint, considering the other parameters you initialize `hog` with:

```
(412 - 16) % 8 = 4    //Problem!!
```

Probably the simplest fix is to increase your window dimensions from `cv::Size(320,412)` to something divisible by 8, perhaps `cv::Size(320,416)`, but the specific size will depend on your specific requirements. Just pay attention to what the assertion is saying!

Comment: I just did, thank you. I had to refresh the page. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: You were correct, sir. Thank you. I appreciate it. Works beautifully now.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance!